# twitter Typeahead input goes undefined when selecting

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I have a typeahead working fine, but when I select an entry, input is filled with "undefined"

[image]

[image]

Any idea why ? Is there a "selecting" event or something that I can use to fill the input with the currently selected value ? I didn't found any information about this behavior on the web.
Here is the typeahead declaration :

```
$('.receivers-input').typeahead({
        minLength: 0,
    }, {
        source: function (query, cb) {
            var Request = $.ajax({
                methode: "POST",
                url: "MessagingService.svc/UserAutocomplete",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charsert=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify({ "inputString": query })
            }).done(function (Response) {
                if (!Response.UserAutocompleteResult.success) {
                    if (!Response.UserAutocompleteResult.message)
                        return;
                    ErmesManager.notify(Response.UserAutocompleteResult.message, null);
                    return;
                }
                cb(Response.UserAutocompleteResult.d);
            });
        },
        templates: {
            suggestion: function (suggestion) {
                return '<p>' + suggestion + '</p>';
            }
        }
    }).on('typeahead:selected', function (event, data) {
        $('.receivers-input').val('');
        ComputeToken(data, true);
    }).on('blur', function (event, data) {
        $('.receivers-input').val(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you post some code?

Comment: I have edit with the typeahead declaration, don't know what else can be usefull

Comment: Did you wait for search engine to be initialized? Why you didn't use bloodhound?

Comment: Because the version of bootstrap i am using doesn't allow me to do it. I don't have any power over the version. Everything is working fine. When I select an entry typeahead:selected is trigger and i am able to take the value of the entry with data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `on('typeahead:cursorchanged', function (event, data) {});` do the trick.
Plus since I use a `placeholder` display is a bit messy. I cleaned it up by adding a `visibility: hidden` on the tt-hint class.

Here are the full modifications :

CSS :

```css
.tt-hint {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Javascript :

```js
 ...
}).on('typeahead:selected', function (event, data) {
    $('.receivers-input.tt-input').val('');
    ComputeToken(data, true);
}).on('blur', function () {
    $('.receivers-input.tt-input').val('');
}).on('typeahead:cursorchanged', function (event, data) {
    $('.receivers-input.tt-input').val(data);
});
```

The cursorchanged event was not documented [here](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#custom-events), if anyone have other sources for documentation I would be glad to have them.

I would add that this question and answer are on a old bootstrap version context. With the latest version (at the moment) typeahead:select would have done the trick too.